# Get historical monthly stock close price in custom format using yfinance

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-manipulation, yfinance

I need to get historical prices of stocks in the following format:

```
[
  {'AMZN': [
    {'Sep 2022': 113},
    {'Oct 2022': 102},
    {'Nov 2022': 92}
  ]},
  {'AAPL': [
    {'Sep 2022': 137},
    {'Oct 2022': 153},
    {'Nov 2022': 147}
  ]},
  {'MSFT': [
    {'Sep 2022': 232},
    {'Oct 2022': 231},
    {'Nov 2022': 241}
  ]}
]
```

But can't figure how to pass proper configuration to yfinance, or if it's not possible to get only close prices, what is the best way to convert output to the format I need. Played around with dataframe.to_dict("records"), but getting only prices without dates.

Here is my code

```
from datetime import date
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'MSFT']
data = yf.download(
        tickers = tickers,
        start="2019-01-01",
        end=date.today().replace(day=2),
        interval = "1mo",
        group_by = 'ticker'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

```
[{ticker: [{str(x.strftime('%b %Y')): int(tickerdata[ticker]['Close'][x])} for x in tickerdata[ticker]['Close'].index]} for ticker in tickers]
```